# Force Close forge.request.ajax

Tags: ajax, trigger.io, forge

I am writing an app that allows file upload to our server. I would like to give users the option to stop the file upload once it has started.

Since the file is being sent via forge.request.ajax, the process runs in the background even if the user leaves the upload screen.

Is there a native way of closing an active forge.request.ajax connection??

My Application allows users to send a file to our server via forge.request - I need to be able to cancel the request - do you have any suggestions as to how to go about this??

Answer (score 2):

Currently, no: although "cancel" messages could be passed through the JS / Native communication bridge, we haven't got logic in the native code to abort partially-sent requests.

I don't *think* there's anything in `java.net.*` that would support that sort of interaction either...

Comment: I want users to be able to cancel a file upload, whats the best way to go about this without the file upload continuing in the background?